# Get the term id belonging to custom taxonomy on a custom single-post-type.php template page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, metabox

I have custom post-type 'sermon' with custom taxonomy 'speaker' attached to it. I wanted to assign custom meta values to the speaker taxonomy, so I am using the taxonomy meta class from Rilwis:

http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/taxonomy-meta-script-for-wordpress.html

I have used the class to add a metabox with the id of 'bio'.

According to his directions, I need to use the following code in order to output the value of the 'bio' meta into my template:

```
$meta = get_option('meta_id');
if (empty($meta)) $meta = array();
if (!is_array($meta)) $meta = (array) $meta;

$meta = isset($meta['term_id']) ? $meta['term_id'] : array();

$value = $meta['field_id'];

echo $value; // if you want to show
```

**Here is what ended up working for me:**

```
$taxmeta = get_option('speaker_meta');
if (empty($taxmeta)) $taxmeta = array();
if (!is_array($taxmeta)) $taxmeta = (array) $meta;

$taxmeta = isset($taxmeta['221']) ? $taxmeta['221'] : array();

$value = $taxmeta['bio'];

echo $value; // if you want to show
```

**Question**

In the above code you see the number '221'. That is the actual term-id of the taxonomy assigned to the post in question (hardcoded to test it out). What I don't understand is how to populate the term_id dynamically.

I can't query the url because this is simply being used on a custom post-type single page, so the term-id is not available there.

How would I modify that snippet to put in the proper term-id belonging to the 'sermon' that I am looking at?

thanks

**edit**

This function does return the proper term_id for me:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, "speaker");
foreach ($terms as $termid) {  
echo $termid->term_id;
}
```

Using that snippet within my loop on my example page returns the value of '221'. If I manually put 221 in place of term_id in the function then it does pull the term meta 'bio' just perfectly.

**Where I am still stuck**

Now that I have that little snippet above which works, how do I get that to output to the term_id so the primary function will work?

```
$meta = isset($meta['term_id']) ? $meta['term_id'] : array();
```

thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `get_the_terms()` function to get the terms of that post in a specific taxonomy:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'speaker' ); //change speaker to whatever you call your taxonomy
//then you can use just the first term
$term_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
```

and now you have the term id inside `$term_id`.

### update

Once you have the term_id you can use it in your function like so:

```
$term_id = $termid->term_id;

$meta = isset($meta[$term_id]) ? $meta[$term_id] : array();
```

Comment: For some reason the term_id is not being picked up when on the custom post-type template file. When I apply the code to the taxonomy template then it works fine. Maybe there are some rules I am missing for pulling the term_id on other template pages? --like does it have to be within the loop or something?

Comment: the code i posted assumes that `$post->ID` is set so yeah it should be inside the loop

Comment: I made absolute certain to place the code within the loop, but it does not seem to return the '221' value. I did try KOt's answer above and it does return 221, although I am not sure how to assign the output to term_id so that I can use it in my function. ideas?

Comment: @Bainternet I edited my question above to show where I am at. Can you help show me how to get term_id populated with the new snippet? I did try your snippet but it was not returning any value, even when in the loop. 

thanks

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: thank you! Manged to learn something new today, which is always a great thing. Turns out my problem was I had to remove the ' ' inside the brackets. Probably very basic php, but something I did not know before now. thanks again!

Comment: glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can done it with `wp_get_post_terms()` function also:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, "speaker");
foreach ($terms as $termid) {  
  echo $termid->term_id;  
}
```

it will display all terms of taxonomy for current post.

**NOTE:** it must be inside the loop

Comment: This function is returning the proper value for me of '221' when used on this page. Now that part is working, how do I 'wrap' that output of 221 into term_id so that I can use it in my function above?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the archive.php page and need the current term:

```
var_dump($wp_query->queried_object);
var_dump($wp_query->queried_object->name);
var_dump($wp_query->queried_object->term_id);
```